# Redirect all blog links from Wordpress.com site to new domain

Tags: plugins, redirect, wordpress.com-hosting

I'm trying to work on redirecting all the blog links from `https://example-source.wordpress.com` to `https://example-target.com/blog/`. The source is a free `wordpress.com` site while the destination is our own domain. It's easy if it's not a `wordpress.com` site since I only need to install a redirect plugin or change something in `.htaccess` but we need to upgrade to a business plan and I have no way of accessing the files.

Any other options to consider to get this done? Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Site Redirect from Wordpress.com (https://en.support.wordpress.com/site-redirect/) to achieve this. While this is a paid for service, it is relatively cheap and you will likely only need to pay once.

Nice site, and as redirects are essential for SEO, it is well worth the effort and small cost to get this right.

Comment: Hi @WPDavid, thanks! When I try to go to the wordpress.com site's wp-admin and click on Plugins, I'm being redirected to our Wordpress.com account showing that I need to upgrade to Business plan. It's no problem if it costs only a few dollars. But it's $20+ and should be paid for 1 whole year. We don't want that since our goal is to fully transfer everything to our new URL.